# Searching for tree item when I don't know exact tree hierarchy

Tags: c#, ui-automation, coded-ui-tests

I am trying to select a tree item in a Coded UI Test, but I don't know the entire hierarchy.

Example:

> - mssql connection
>
>   - Tables
>
>     - *Unknown*
>
>       - FirstName

Is there a way to search for this FirstName tree item and specify that it is so many levels deep, without specifying the entire path?

It doesn't look like any of the Search Configuration properties will do this.

Comment: In theory smart search would find it but in a larger tree it is probably going to time out first (or if unknown is radically different it might ignore it). There is a MaxDepth search property which might help cut down the number of wrong search paths assuming you know it is always going to X controls deep.

Answer (score 1):

If FirstName is unique in the tree, then you can use PInvoke, and you won't need to specify the depth:

```
    public static List<IntPtr> GetChildWindows(IntPtr parent)
    {
        var result = new List<IntPtr>();
        var listHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(result);
        try
        {
            var childProc = new User32.EnumWindowsProc(EnumWindow);
            User32.EnumChildWindows(parent, childProc, GCHandle.ToIntPtr(listHandle));
        }
        finally
        {
            if (listHandle.IsAllocated)
                listHandle.Free();
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static bool EnumWindow(IntPtr handle, IntPtr pointer)
    {
        var gch = GCHandle.FromIntPtr(pointer);
        var list = gch.Target as List<IntPtr>;
        if (list == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidCastException("GCHandle Target could not be cast as List<IntPtr>");
        }
        list.Add(handle);
        // Modify this to check to see if you want to cancel the operation, then return a null here
        return true;
    }

    public delegate bool EnumWindowsProc(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool EnumChildWindows(IntPtr window, EnumWindowsProc callback, IntPtr i);

    // sample usage:
    public void findWindowUser32()
    {
        foreach (IntPtr child in GetChildWindows(User32.FindWindow(null, "Untitled - Notepad")))
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(100);
            User32.GetClassName(child, sb, sb.Capacity);

            if (sb.ToString() == "Edit")
            {
                uint wparam = 0 << 29 | 0;
                User32.PostMessage(child, WindowsConstants.WM_KEYDOWN, (IntPtr)Keys.H, (IntPtr)wparam);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: +1 for a different way to look at the problem. How does the speed of using PInvoke compare to using the built in test framework?

Comment: Funny you should ask.  Performance turns out to be one of the reasons that I like this solution.  The performance is much better, most likely because only window handles are being gathered by the GetChildWindows call.  The additional call to get the name (GetClassName) doesn't add much overhead either.  Using the UIAutomation classes and calling GetChildren with TreeScope set to Descendants also works well, but gathers much more data and is much slower.

Comment: Note:  I think that CodedUI uses MSAA, the UIAutomation classes, and probably more techniques.

Answer (score 0):

When your control was mapped in the UI map, perhaps the full hierarchy was used, eg

mssql connection
-Tables
--Unknown1
---FirstName

resulted in 4 mapped controls.

You can edit the uimap .xml file manually carefully removing the -Unknown1 element, and making sure that MatchExactHierarchy is turned off.
That way the search will originally fail, move on to using heuristics to look for elements deeper in the tree than the immediate children and should find your control.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public static UITestControl GetTreeItem(UITestControl TreeControl, string ItemName, bool ContainsTrue = true)
    {
        AutomationElement tree = AutomationElement.FromHandle(TreeControl.WindowHandle);
        System.Windows.Automation.ControlType controlType = tree.Current.ControlType;
        //Get collection of tree nodes.
        AutomationElementCollection treeNodeCollection = null;
        treeNodeCollection = tree.FindAll(TreeScope.Descendants,
                new System.Windows.Automation.PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty,
                        System.Windows.Automation.ControlType.TreeItem));
        UITestControl ReqTreeItem = new UITestControl();
        foreach (AutomationElement item in treeNodeCollection)
        {
            if ((item.Current.Name == ItemName) && (!ContainsTrue))
            {
                ReqTreeItem = UITestControlFactory.FromNativeElement(item, "UIA");
                break;
            }
            if ((item.Current.Name.Contains(ItemName)) && (ContainsTrue))
            {
                ReqTreeItem = UITestControlFactory.FromNativeElement(item, "UIA");
                break;
            }
        }
        return ReqTreeItem;
    }
```